# How do I get rid of the error "Argument 1 missing or nil" when I'm trying to make my datastore?

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this error but I've had no luck, is there any way to get rid of the error?

Me and a friend are working on a game and this is the script I've put in serverscriptservice. I'm trying to help with scripting but the script refuses to work. Any help please?

```lua
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local WinsDataStore = DataStoreService:GetOrderedDataStore("WinsRathersCamel")

local function Update()
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        local Data = WinsDataStore:GetSortedAsync(false, 5)
        local WinsPage = Data:GetCurrentPage()
        for rank, data in pairs(WinsPage) do
            local Username = game.Players:GetNameFromUserIdAsync(tonumber(data.key))
            local Name = Username
            local Wins = data.value
            local isonleaderboard = false
            for i, v in pairs(game.Workspace["Total Wins"].Leaderboard.Holder:GetChildren()) do
                if v.Player.Text == Name then
                    isonleaderboard = true
                    break
                end
            end
            
            if Wins and isonleaderboard == false then
                local newlibframe = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("LeaderboardFrame"):Clone()
                newlibframe.Player.Text = Name
                newlibframe.Wins = Wins
                newlibframe.Rank = "#"..rank
                newlibframe.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, newlibframe.Position.Y.Scale + (.08 * #game.Workspace["Total Wins"].Leaderboard.Holder:GetChildren()), 0)
                newlibframe.Parent = game.Workspace["Total Wins"].Leaderboard.Holder
            end
        end
    end)
    
    if not success then
        print(errormessage)
    end
end

while true do
    for _, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        WinsDataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-Wins",player.leaderstats.Wins.Value)
    end
    
    for _, frame in pairs(game.Workspace["Total Wins"].Leaderboard.Holder:GetChildren()) do
        frame:Destroy()
    end
    
    Update()
    print("Updated")
end
```

Comment: what line is the error coming from?

Comment: The error is coming from line 34. "Print(errormessage)".

Comment: That's where the error is printed, but where is it caused?

Comment: It won't tell me. It just says "Argument 1 missing or nil".

Comment: Hmm, unusual. You can use `xpcall` to get more detail. Without line I can only guess. Could be `tonumber(data.key)` because its not a valid number. At least its the only location where you could pass a nil if I see this correctly.

Comment: How would I interpret `xpcall` into the script?

Comment: Just comment out the pcall lines and see what line throws

Comment: I did that. Luke100000 was right. It comes from line 9 which is where `tonumber(data.key)` is. Is it possible to fix?

Comment: on the line after `for rank, data in pairs(WinsPage) do` what do you get if you print out `print(data)`?

Comment: So it should be like:
`for rank, data in pairs(WinsPage) do
     print(data)
     --- Rest of code`
?

Comment: @Sh3l0nC00p3r it should.